# Tensorflow: ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.90GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory

There is a question that I don't understand.

```
Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.90GiB. 
The caller indicates that this is not a failure, 
but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
```

What is the sentence mean?

I have read the source code. But I cann't understand because of my poor ability.
The memory size of GPU is 6GB, the result of memory use that I use tfprof analysis is about 14GB.
That is beyond the memory size of GPU.
**The sentence is showing weather tensorflow allocate the memory of CPU or use the good algorithm about the use of memory of GPU?**

```
The version of tensorflow that I use is 1.2.
```

The infomition of GPU as fllows:

- name: GeForce GTX TITAN Z
- major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8755
- Total memory: 5.94GiB
- Free memory: 5.87GiB

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0' 


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
#sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
def weight_variable(shape):
    init = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(init)

def bias_variable(shape):
    init = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(init)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])


W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)


W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)


W_f1 = weight_variable([7*7*64, 1024])
b_f1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_f1) + b_f1)


keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_f2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_f2 = bias_variable([10])
y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_f2) + b_f2)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


test_images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
test_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])


tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()


for i in range(100):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(10000)
    if (i%10 == 0):  
        train_accurancy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob : 1.0})
        print("step %d, traning accurancy %g" % (i, train_accurancy))
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob : 0.5}, options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE), run_metadata=run_metadata)

tf.contrib.tfprof.model_analyzer.print_model_analysis(
    tf.get_default_graph(),
    run_meta=run_metadata,
    tfprof_options=tf.contrib.tfprof.model_analyzer.PRINT_ALL_TIMING_MEMORY)

test_images = mnist.test.images[0:300, :]
test_labels = mnist.test.labels[0:300, :]
print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval({x: test_images, y_: test_labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

The warning:

```
2017-08-10 21:37:44.589635: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.90GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-08-10 21:37:46.208897: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.61GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
```

The result of tfprof:

```
==================Model Analysis Report======================
_TFProfRoot (0B/14854.97MB, 0us/7.00ms)
```

Answer (score 4):

you're using the GPU, and your batchSize is **1000**  it's a lot for 10 classes! make a smaller batch size like 10to20 and augment the range to 10e4 or even 10e3. 
This problem is well [known](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/136) . Any  if you definitely want to use 10000 as batch size, tell tensorflow to use the [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu) using :

```
tf.device('/cpu:0')
```

Comment: It can run without error, which make me confuse. I don't know why. The result of tfprof is 14854.97MB, which is beyond my memory size of GPU.

Comment: Do you know anything about what tensorflow to do when the memory of GPU is run out. It will use the memory and compute of CPU?

Comment: @qihao sorry that  it tooks so long. Sorry  the only work around that I found is making the batch smaller, for your the MNIST dataset u can definitly use a smaller batch size. it's bug and  as far as I know they didn't solve it. for bigger dataset you will definitly need to use the GPU.

Comment: Hi, I too am getting the same error as "Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 195.25MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but this may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available".

But the model is getting trained properly only, losses are decreasing in each step. My batchsize is 16. Since it is mentionedin the warning that, it is NOT failure, and would inc. performance if more GPU RAM is used, it is not any problem right? Is it fine to continue training?